# Extract URL from a website including archived links

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

I'm crawling a news website to extracts all links including the archived ones which is typical of a news website. The site [here](http://e.vnexpress.net/news/business) has a a button `View More Stories` that loads more website articles. Now this code below

```
def find_urls():
start_url = "e.vnexpress.net/news/business"
r = requests.get("http://" + start_url)
data = r.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "html.parser")
links = soup.findAll('a')
url_list = []
for url in links:
    all_link = url.get('href')
    if all_link.startswith('http://e.vnexpress.net/news/business'):
        url_list.append(all_link)
return set(url_list)
```

successfully load quite a few url but how do I load more here is a snippet of the button

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" id="vnexpress_folder_load_more" data-page="2"
                           data-cate="1003895">
                            View more stories
                        </a>
```

Can someone help me out. Thanks.

Comment: Load more stories are coming from `post` request. Therefore first construst next page url and then do `post` request, This is your next page url http://e.vnexpress.net/news/business?cate_id=1003895&page=2 . You need to pass 2 parameters `cate_id` and `page`

Comment: @akashkarothiya can you give me more explanation? regards!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a browser like selenium to click the button till the button disappears or disables. Finally you can scrape the entire page using beautifulsoup in one go.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

#initializing browser
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.set_window_size(1120, 550)

driver.get("http://e.vnexpress.net/news/news")

# run this till button is present
elem = driver.find_element_by_id('vnexpress_folder_load_more'))
elem.click()
```

Comment: Yeah great this works. But how can I make it to run a couple of times?  I discovered it worked only ones. I tried reading about selenium from the documentation couldn't find something relevant..

Comment: @Jeremiah can you please explain how you want it to run ?

Comment: From what I understand the `elem.click()` loads the next page. What I want it to achieve is to continue to run repeatedly until I specify a condition for it to stop probably after crawling about 100 url's.